# 1196 Duplicate Symbols for architecture React-Native

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I tried building my project after doing some updates to my fbsdk, after removing errors for fbsdk related errors, this happens. I tried building to test out the updates but this happens.

This is the error [https://i.imgur.com/vdJzHbz.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajd1U.png)

I tried `commonblocks to No, target.name ==" React" remove from project`

Maybe someone can help me solve this.

Comment: you should try to remove `import React from "react";`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Xcode > Pods > Targets Support Files > Pods-{TARGET-NAME} find
   "OTHER_LDFLAGS" and remove only "-ObjC" in these two files:
   Pods-{TARGET-NAME}.release.xcconfig &
   Pods-{TARGET-NAME}.debug.xcconfig
2. Go to project main target > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags:
   Make sure no "-ObjC" is left in the value
3. deleted the build/Build folder in ios and run-ios again. maybe It will works
   .

Comment: Remove it from where from my src /.js files? if I do that Android build wouldn't work

Comment: @drini There will be a place where 'React' is used twice in the import.

Comment: I did a search of all my project folder for any dupe imports but all imported only one line of imported ```import React from "react"```

Comment: could you try change? `import { Component } from "react"; and class App extends Component {`

Comment: I want to clear this, so I would change my ```import React from "react";``` to ``` import {component} from "react";``` ?

Comment: tried to changing ```import React from "react"; to import {component} from "react"; ``` I still receive those errors